UE5 Unresolved External Symbol From Another Module
I'm having trouble with my new module.
In my OnlineSubsystemUnincModule.cpp I have IMPLEMENT_MODULE(FOnlineSubsystemUnincModule, OnlineSubsystemUninc);
In my ProjectName.uproject I have
{
        "Name": "OnlineSubsystemUninc",
        "Type": "Runtime",
        "LoadingPhase": "Default"
},

In my primary module's .Build.cs I have
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[]
        {
            // Other modules...
            "OnlineSubsystemUninc"
        });

in the Modules array.
As a test, I added a Print() method to my FOnlineSubsystemUninc class, but when I build I receive the following error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl FOnlineSubsystemUninc::Print(void)" (?Print@FOnlineSubsystemUninc@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl AShadowNetworkCharacter::OnSelectPressed(void)" (?OnSelectPressed@AShadowNetworkCharacter@@QEAAXXZ)   ShadowNetwork   D:\uninc\snet-client\ShadowNetwork\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\ShadowNetworkCharacter.cpp.obj 1       

Below is the actual code trying to call the Print method
FOnlineSubsystemUninc* OnlineSubsystemUninc = static_cast<FOnlineSubsystemUninc*>(OnlineSubsystem);
if (OnlineSubsystemUninc == nullptr)
{
    UE_LOG(LogCharacter, Warning, TEXT("FOnlineSubsystemUninc static_cast failed"));
    return;
}
OnlineSubsystemUninc->Print(); // ERROR: causes unresolved external symbol

I've double checked all of the naming. I've looked online for days, but come up empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What does the definition of Print look like? Do you export it with ONLINESUBSYSTEMINC_API?
